# PostgreSQL 10 user delete

Tags: windows, postgresql

I have PostgreSQL 9.0 on my system with a `postgres` user.
And my application runs well in this version.

Now, I want to upgrade to PostgreSQL 10.0. I have installed it successfully and the application also works properly.

When I want to uninstall PostgreSQL 10.0 through my own installer, I uninstall it and delete the service and user using following commands:

```
sc delete postgres_service10
net user postgres /delete
```

When I delete the `postgres` user, it deletes the entire user folder from users and the PostgreSQL 9.0 service is also removed along with the user.

How do i remove only PostgreSQL 10.0 user from `users->postgres` folder?

Comment: Of course removing a user removes the user's directory in Windows.

Comment: Is there a way to remove version specific details from postgres user folder?

Comment: If you want to keep that user for the Postgres 10 service, then apparently you can't delete the user (however Postgres has not required a dedicated Windows user for the service for a long time) I have no idea how you installed Postgres 9.0 but if you removed the service, you can simply delete the Postgres 9.0 specific data directory manually using the `del` command (or through the Windows explorer or any other file manager)

Comment: yes thank you.
I use 'uninstall-postgresql.exe' to uninstall it.
sometimes service or user remains even after uninstall and creates problem when you try to install it again.
Thatswhy i was trying to remove that user.